# popper.js Offsets separated by white space(s) are deprecated, use a comma (,) instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, popper.js, atlaskit

I am having this error in my console every time I open the dropdown from this package @atlaskit/dropdown-menu and my error is this one: popper.js: Offsets separated by white space(s) are deprecated, use a comma (,) instead. Thank you so much

I went to popper.js

```
  // Detect if the offset string contains a pair of values or a single one
  // they could be separated by comma or space
  var divider = fragments.indexOf(find(fragments, function (frag) {
    return frag.search(/,|\s/) !== -1;
  }));


  if (fragments[divider] && fragments[divider].indexOf(',') === -1) {

    console.warn('Offsets separated by white space(s) are deprecated, use a comma (,) instead.');
  }   `
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: hey @MosèRaguzzini thank you for your time, this the code from popper.js: https://codepen.io/ohlalo/pen/dBwGOg?editors=1010